# Dynamically create multiple button and assign single click and double click comand

Tags: vb.net

I created multiple button dynamically inside a panel based on multiple click on add button. Each button deletes When I click on it.
I want each button to delete when I single click on it, and say hello when I double click. Thank you.

I have tried using this code to delete which works fine, but I cannot figure how to assign seperate code to display hello when I double click or right click on it without affecting delete aspect of it.

```
Private Sub btnDynamic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Reference the Button which was clicked.
    Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)

    'Determine the Index of the Button.
    Dim index As Integer = Integer.Parse(button.Name.Split("_")(1))

    'Find the TextBox using Index and remove it.
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("btnDynamic_" & index), True)(0))
    'Remove the Button.
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(button)
    'Rearranging the Location controls.
    For Each btn As Button In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        Dim controlIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(btn.Name.Split("_")(1))
        If (controlIndex > index) Then
            Dim btn1 As Button = CType(FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find(("btnDynamic_" & controlIndex), True)(0), Button)
            btn1.Top = (btn.Top - 25)
            'txt.Top = (txt.Top - 25)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is the create button code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim count As Integer = Form2.FlowLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType(Of Button).ToList.Count
    Dim button As Button = New Button
    button.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(28, 21)
    button.Name = "btnDynamic_" & (count + 1)
    button.Text = TextBox1.Text
    AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Me.button_click
    Form2.FlowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(button)
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to handle the location of controls inside a FlowLayoutPanel.  It handles it for you.

Comment: You can't handle it, you can only adjust with margins and padding.

Comment: Buttons have the double-click event turned off by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable DoubleClick option first.
You do so with:

```
Public Class DoubleClickButton
    Inherits Button

    Public Sub New()
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick Or ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, True)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then create a "DoubleClick" and "SingleClick" methods and assign them to (new custom) buttons when you are creating them.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For x = 0 To 2
        Dim ButtonX As New DoubleClickButton
        ButtonX.Text = x
        AddHandler ButtonX.MouseClick, AddressOf SingleClickE
        AddHandler ButtonX.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf DoubleClickE
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ButtonX)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SingleClickE(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Hello!")
End Sub

Private Sub DoubleClickE(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(sender)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahem.  `Dim ButtonX As New Button`

Comment: Ahem why? It's a capital X, even if it were a small x I don't expect it to put numbers there.

Comment: You aren't using the custom button you created.  :-)

Comment: I don't know of I am getting it wrong. I tried the code above but it does not triger or respond.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for attempting to answer my question. I have been able to figure it out. I intend firing diffrent events with dynamically created buttons using single click, double click or right click. I ended up using single and right click command. Though would have prefered double click, but it is ok. Below is the code.

```
'Create buttons
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim button As New Button
            button.Text = i
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf SingleClickE
            AddHandler button.MouseDown, AddressOf RightClickE
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button)
        Next
    End Sub

'Fire it up with single click
    Private Sub SingleClickE(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        MsgBox("Hello World")
    End Sub

'Fire it up with Right Click
    Private Sub RightClickE(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(button)
        End If
    End Sub
```